# Загрузка в браузере Chrome файла json - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Дошел в учебнике по js до node.js и есть первая задача где должен загружаться файл json с сервера но мне выдает такую ошибку:

> index.html:34 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Horchynskyi/phones-async/phones.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Почитал комментарии многие пишут что работает вроде как только на мозиле почему так?
код сервера: и код html:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.', {
  cache: 0
});

function accept(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/phones.json') {
    // искусственная задержка для наглядности
    setTimeout(function() {
      file.serve(req, res);
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    file.serve(req, res);
  }
}
// ------ запустить сервер -------
if (!module.parent) {
  http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
} else {
  exports.accept = accept;
}
```

в html:

```
function loadPhones() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
    button.innerHTML = 'Готово!';
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      // обработать ошибку
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    } else {
      // вывести результат
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
  button.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...';
  button.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно ваша клиентская сторона открыта просто как html файл на диске в папке `C:/Users/Horchynskyi/phones-async/index.html`, потому ссылка формируется на файл (`file:///C:/Users/Horchynskyi/phones-async/phones.json`), а не по протоколу HTTP . Для того чтобы работало, либо открывайте свой клиент, загружая страницу `index.html` с того сервера, где лежит `phones.json`, либо укажите полный путь с доменом и портом в этом месте `xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true)` -> `xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/phones.json', true)`. Плюс нужно установить заголовки на сервере, который файл отдает `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: ага, а можно ещё спросить как открывать index.html с сервера?

Comment: Так как вы используете модуль node-static, достаточно разместить файл Index.html в директории, где лежит json файл и обратиться к нему через браузер введя в адресную строку http://localhost:8080/index.html. **P.S** Не забывайте помечать ответы как полезные, если они вам помогли.